# SQL Query with counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am using MS-SQL and I have a table with the following columns:

SessionId | Date | first name | last name 
i would like to do group by sessionId and then get the row with the max date.
in additional to that i would like to count the sessionsId.

for example:

```
xxx | 21/12/2012 | f1 | l1
xxx | 20/12/2012 | f2 | l2
yyy | 21/12/2012 | f3 | l3
yyy | 20/12/2012 | f4 | l4
```

i would like to get the following rows:

```
xxx | 21/12/2012 | f1 | l1 | 2
yyy | 21/12/2012 | f3 | l3 | 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: @SimonMartin - Why did you remove the MySQL tag and tag it with tsql tag instead?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: I guess because the question starts with "I use **MS-SQL**..."

Comment: As a_horse_with_no_name says; your question starts with **MS-SQL** not MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  s.SessionId,
  s.Date,
  s.firstname,
  s.lastname,
  m.SessionsCount
FROM Sessions s
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT SessionID, COUNT(SessionID) AS SessionsCount, MAX(Date) LatestDate
   FROM sessions
   GROUP BY SessionID
) m  ON m.SessionID  = s.SessionID
    AND m.LatestDate = s.Date;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/286fd/2)

This will give you:

```
| SESSIONID |       DATE | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | SESSIONSCOUNT |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|       xxx | 21/12/2012 |        f1 |       l1 |             2 |
|       yyy | 21/12/2012 |        f3 |       l3 |             2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This will simply do,

```
select a.date1,a.first_name,a.last_name
from(select row_number() 
over(partition by SessionId order by SessionId) rnk,date1,first_name,last_name
from table1) a where a.rnk=1
```

Sample Answer:

```
DATE1       FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
21/12/2012       f1       l1
21/12/2012       f3       l3
```

[**Live Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1187/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sessionid, a.date, firstname, lastname, COUNT(sessionid) sessioncnt 
FROM (SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER BY sessionid, date DESC) AS a 
GROUP BY sessionid;
```